# Difficulties in the Jobeet Tutorial with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm kinda new in symfony2, and I'm try to follow the tutorial of the jobeet. But I'm stuck in the part where "***To tell Doctrine about our objects, we will create “metadata” files***". In the tutorial there is the code:

```
    # src/Ens/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Category.orm.yml
    Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category:
      type: entity
      table: category
      id:
        id:
          type: integer
          generator: { strategy: AUTO }
      fields:
        name:
          type: string
          length: 255
          unique: true
      oneToMany:
        jobs:
          targetEntity: Job
          mappedBy: category
        category_affiliates:
          targetEntity: CategoryAffiliate
          mappedBy: category
```

But what do I do with it, where do I save it, in my project? And with what extension?
Can anyone help me with this. Here is the tutorial.[Symfony2 jobeet tutorial](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/27/symfony2-jobeet-day-3-the-data-model/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you may want to check out the version of the Jobeet tutorial for Symfony 2.3, it's easier to follow with the more recent Symfony version as the one you're looking over was written for Symfony 2.0.

[Symbony 2.3 version of the Jobeet tutorial](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/tag/symfony2-jobeet/page/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the code you show is a comment and indicates everything about the file:

```
# src/Ens/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Category.orm.yml
```

The file should be called: `Category.orm.yml` and should be saved in the folder `src/Ens/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/`.